# Discussion questions

Tags: discussion

Are discussion question okay? I'd like to start a discussion on why XSS should be renamed Script Injection, and if there is agreement on that (I've got a few arguments), if and how we could go about promoting it.

If the question would get shot down anyway, I wouldn't want to waste time writing down the arguments...

Answer (score 4):

My opinion is yes. There are naturally a lot of subjective questions in IT security, like questions of policy, disclosure practices and current recommendations that will turn out to be open-ended discussions. While those questions aren't a good fit for stack overflow, I think they're a necessary part of an IT Security site.

Comment: +1 i've asked several already

Answer (score 4):

I would say that discussions are OK when they will lead to some common conclusion, not just philosophical humble opinions expression. It is clear that discussions like "Windows vs Linux"  must be avoided, but anyway, new topics should be created with care and aim to be useful for all.

As for current example with XSS - I would say no. The reason is just simple - no one will start using new term "Script Injection" even it could have obvious reasons. There are many historical terms that are used widely and well-known. I think such topics also should be avoided.