# Should the FAQ contain guidelines around asking questions that may compromise security?

Tags: discussion

With the increasing use of social media mining tools such as [Maltego](http://www.paterva.com/) should we be stressing that people should think carefully about what they are asking questions on? Especially if they are asking questions about their companies security posture or configuration.

If I was going to do a profile of a company there could be some rich pickings in this site as it develops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, thats a pretty good point.
Though at times it will be difficult to get the information one needs, without revealing some sensitive details... and keeping it anonymous is also not always possible, but we shouldn't make it easier to find that stuff out.

You should probably add this as an answer to "[What should our FAQ contain?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13/33)"; though theres nothing there yet hopefully it will become the hub question.