# Is it a right place to ask about viruses?

Tags: discussion, faq, asking-questions

I think my computer is infected into a new virus! Can i ask some question about treats of this virus? Microsoft Security Essentials can't find it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a question for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 4):

@Jalal, as @Rory said, this is not the right place for this.

IT Security is a place to discuss the principles of security, privacy, risk analysis and management, and so forth, especially as apply to IT, companies, and products.

Details of a specific virus, antivirus product, or how to fix your computer, are definitely out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

I'm for HoLyVieR's suggestion of putting this in the FAQ.  Can we put this question in the FAQ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers, this type of question would not be on-topic for security.stackexchange.com. Of course, the question "is this question on-topic" *is* on-topic for meta.security.stackexchange.com...and now my head hurts :).

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to have questions about *secure* means of mitigating virus damage (for example in a specific OS environment or as part of a specific infrastructure.