# How and when should we use the Community Wiki feature?

Tags: discussion

Im wondering when, if ever, we should use the community wiki feature which we often see on SO.

Is it even implemented in our site?

Also have a look at [discussion-questions](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/discussion-questions) . Discussion questions and other questions which arent easy to make a common conclusion on are often tagged as Community Wiki on SO, but is it the same in our site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to mark *questions* as community wiki became a source of confusion and pain so it was removed: [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better)

More times than not (*many* more times) community wiki was applied to compensate for poor topics that do not belong. But somewhat subjective questions can still be okay; just follow the guidelines for *good* subjective questions: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Individual *answers* can still be marked community wiki. And if you really, really feel that a question must be community wiki, flag it for moderator attention. Moderators can still convert questions to community wiki. But it should be somewhat rare.

Comment: Thanks Robert, was I also correct that questions with many responses are automatically made CW?

Comment: @AviD: Yes. +30 answers will make it CW. So will 10 edits by the original author, as will edits by 5 different users.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, CW can be applied to answers only.
CW on questions are only applied automatically by the system, (I think) after the question passes something like 30 answers.

I believe this now applies to SO too, though it didn't used to be like that.

Comment: Aha. If that is so then they changed it from back when I used to be at SO :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used CW on an answer ([this answer](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/so-what-should-our-faq-contain/42#42), specifically) in an effort to invite community editing of the answer. That evidently hasn't happened, so perhaps that's a sign of a *bad* use of CW ;-).

Comment: Heh, true that. Truthfully, I've only seen CW used as a kind of rep-protection for controversial answers, or some kind of "altruistic" declaration. If an answer needs to get edited, it will probably get edited regardless.