# Questions that are more like discussion

Tags: discussion

Theres already been asked if discussion questions are okay [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/discussion-questions), but when you ask such question with no definitive answer, when should one accept an answer?

Should you edit your own post with as much good info from the answers?

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

I think that is worthwhile, yes - as it still provides useful knowledge to someone who arrives here from a search engine. Accept the useful answers - develop the question if necessary, but either way, get a conclusion written down which would satisfy the knowledge-hungry.

Comment: While I agree, the point of the discussion is that sometimes there *isn't* an unambiguous conclusion. Sometimes it will be just a collection of facts, opinions, and viewpoints - which while are all equally relevant, are also all equally valid- or invalid, depending on which is yours or is the most convincing. Now, while I would usually be correct <grin>, others might think they are correct, and it may not always be conclusive. There **are** subjective issues, depending on risk tolerance/appetite and personal tradeoffs.

Comment: Oh yeah - think my wording isn't ideal. I don't really mean everyone must agree and come to one conclusion - I just mean if it is just a collection of opinions, but there are some that all commentators agree on it could be valuable to highlight these and accept them as the most useful answer points.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that @Rory. Here is where community wiki would come in handy...